# Can't edit values on MatDatePicker range. Angular 12

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I've implemented a date range picker with MatDatePicker as described in the documentation https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples It works very well, but if I want to edit my selected values seems hard to select a new range.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sslmeg?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

[image: Invalid dates]

It only lets me change one date, setting the second to a default value of `01/01/1970`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zl9qdr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

After removing `(dateChange)="dateConverter($event)"` in input selector it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I use that converter to store the dates values in javascript date objects instead of moment date ones.  I'm guessing now I'll do that inside the onSubmit method.

Thank you @AlexYu